# Microsoft Azure Get specific role members as a normal user

Tags: azure

I would like to write a stored procedure which will be executed by
a normal user through which he will be able to see the list of
all specific role members Example : 'HSS'.
How can I do that for the normal user ?

I have this :

> select r.name as role_name, m.name as member_name from
> sys.database_role_members rm  inner join sys.database_principals r on
> rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id inner join
> sys.database_principals m on rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
> where r.name = 'HSS'

However when normal user runs it he sees only his name...

Comment: By adding one parameter to the stored procedure like **`CREATE  PROCEDURE FirstSchema.GetRoleMembersForThisUser
@UserName`**  and use that in query while filtering  **`WHERE r.name  =  'HSS'
AND m.name  = @UserName;`** then only that particular `user` can see only his name like [this](https://i.imgur.com/zvzjlbw.png).

Comment: I want the user to see all the members, not just his name.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft Azure: Get specific role members as a normal user

After creating the stored procedure in the `admin` user, a few permissions need to be given to the normal user to get specific role members as a normal user, as shown below.

```sql
USE <database name>;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::<Schema Name> TO <second admin>;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO <second admin>;
```

In the above query, `database name` is used to specify the particular database, `Schema Name` is the name created while creating the `schema`, and `second admin` is the normal user. After executing the stored procedure in the main `admin`, another admin `second admin`, has been created. Below is the output where a normal user can see all the members like `admin` after executing the stored procedure in the `second admin`.

**Output:**

[image]